# Overlay text over stealth in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to make my text overlay over the stealth, as if that part of stealth is covered by the text and thus invisible.

What I have now is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, calc, positioning, fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) {A node};
    \node[draw,align=center] (b) at (0,-5) {Another\\node};
    \draw[-stealth] (a.west) --++ (-1, 0) |- (b.west)node[pos=0.4, above]{Text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives me

[image]

As can be seen the stealth "goes through" the text node, which is undesired.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I suggest you to have a look to the library `decorations.text`.

Comment: You can add `fill=white` to the node. You can use the `decorations.markings` library (which doesn’t work good for lines with an arrow tip, but you could only use the vertical part) or you place the node first and then you connect the nodes. See [path with both mark connection node and arrow tip](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99945)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Qrrbrbirlbel suggested, it's easy to place `text node` with a `path` command and `draw` the path with a posterior command. This way you don't need to `fill` text node to cover the stealth or use `decorations` to place a `node` over it.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) {A node};
    \node[draw,align=center] (b) at (0,-5) {Another\\node};
    % next command will place text node where you want. Assign a name to it.
    \path (a.west) --++ (-1, 0) |- (b.west)node[pos=0.4, above](text) {Text};
    % Draw a fragmented stealth
    \draw (a) -| (text);
    \draw[-stealth] (text) |- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]