# Breaking an arrow with text in a flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, arrows

is there a way to "break" a vertical arrow by text going through it in a flowchart? I just need a gap in the arrow for the text to go through.

Comment: Put a node `midway` and give it white background.

Comment: Related: [path with both mark connection node and arrow tip](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99945)

Comment: If you can place the node before you draw the arrow, you can use it as an intermediate point: `\draw[->] (start) -- (node) -- (target);`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using the following link :
[path with both mark connection node and arrow tip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99945)

[image]

and here is the code :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  mylabel/.style = {font=\footnotesize, midway, fill=white, anchor=center}
}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm, auto]
    \node [block] (a) {a};
    \node [block, below of=a] (b) {b};
    \draw (a) -- (b) node[mylabel] {Test};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn’t overwrite the `label` key … Also: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372)

Comment: Right, I changed the name