# Delete part of drawing (or draw in transparent color)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking for a way to *delete* part of a previously drawn picture.

An easy way is drawing in the background color, but that does not work
if the background is transparent.

Here's an example `file.tex`:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=100,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % draw a black line   
  \draw (0,0) -- (2,1);
  % "delete" part of the line
  \draw[fill,color=white](0.5,0) rectangle (1.5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I use the `standalone` class to produce a single picture.  When run
with `pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex`, this builds both:

- `file.pdf`
- `file.png`

The pdf looks fine, since background is indeed white.

The png is built through the imagemagick `convert` tool and has a
transparent background, and so the "deleted" part appears as a white
rectangle.

I know I can use the `-alpha remove -background white` options for
`convert` to turn the background white but I'd rather like the
reverse: having transparent background, including the "deleting
rectangle".

I thought about using a *reverse clip* (as in
[How can I invert a 'clip' selection within TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/how-can-i-invert-a-clip-selection-within-tikz))
but I can't know in advance which part I don't want to be drawn, thus
the need to delete rather than avoid drawing the unwanted part in the
first place.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: TikZ supports [the `transparency group` of type `knockout`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transparency#tikz/transparency:group) but not many PDF viewers do (neither does the unofficial online version of the manual I've linked to). You could also save the needed clip when you know it, write it to the `aux` file and then apply it on the second run. You could also place an empty rectangular box along a path with the [`mark connection node`](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf/decoration/mark:connection:node) decoration where PGF/TikZ automatically draws to seperate lines. What's your actual usecase?

Comment: Indeed, the knockout transparency group is exactly what I'm looking for!  Too bad it's not well supported.  The mupdf viewer does support it but imagemagick's convert tool (latest version 7.1.0-52) does not.
My use case is the user using macros to describe sequential events, with some events affecting the drawing of previous events, thus the need to erase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the idea to save the path to the `aux` file so that it is available at the next run.

I didn't test it much but for this example it works.
I might have [experience](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121054/16595) with using the `aux` file but I'm no expert. Externalizing the picture with the `external` library won't work.

---

On any path of TikZ you can use the

- `remember path = <name>` key so that it will be available at the next compilation and the
- `remembered path = <name>` key that uses this path (if it is available).

The key will use `\pgfpictureid` as a prefix so that you can specify the same path name in different pictures.

---

I've also defined a `reverse clip` key that supports both a clockwise as well as a counter clockwise rectangle with maximum supported size. This is done on the PGF layer and with the `q`uick commands for three reasons:

1. they are quicker,
2. they ignore transtormations and
3. they don't update the bounding box (though, your `\path[remember path=…]` might use `overlay` anyway.

---

This is how you use it:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[left color=blue, right color=green] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\clip[remembered path=box];
\draw (0,0) -- (2,1);
\path[remember path=box] (0.5, 0) rectangle (1.5, 1) [reverse clip];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz, convert]{standalone}
% Part 1: Quick PGF versions of reverse clips.
%% * uses quick commands that
%%   * ignore transformations and
%%   * don't contribute to the bounding box (we use overlay though anyway)
%% * only uses 16000pt since this is what PGF does, too (TeX'd allow 16384pt)
%% * clockwise and counterclockwise for nonzero and even odd rule
%%
\tikzset{% quick versions of reverse clips
  reverse clip/.is choice,
  reverse clip/clockwise/.code={%
    \pgfpathqmoveto{16000pt}{16000pt}%
    \pgfpathqlineto{16000pt}{-16000pt}%
    \pgfpathqlineto{-16000pt}{-16000pt}%
    \pgfpathqlineto{-16000pt}{16000pt}%
    \pgfpathclose},
  reverse clip/counter clockwise/.code={%
    \pgfpathqmoveto{16000pt}{16000pt}%
    \pgfpathqlineto{-16000pt}{16000pt}%
    \pgfpathqlineto{-16000pt}{-16000pt}%
    \pgfpathqlineto{16000pt}{-16000pt}%
    \pgfpathclose},
  reverse clip/.default=counter clockwise}

% Part 2: The actual keys
%         that save/use the path to/from the aux file.
%% * remember path will does what ever you do on the path
%%   and save it to the aux file
%% * remembered path will set the remembers path (if available)
%%   and use it as specified
%%
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  remember path/.code={%
    \tikz@addmode{%
      \expandafter\pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath\csname qrr@tikzpath@\pgfpictureid @#1\endcsname
      \immediate\write\pgfutil@auxout{%
        \noexpand\expandafter\gdef\noexpand\csname qrr@tikzpath@\pgfpictureid @#1\endcsname{%
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\unexpanded
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname qrr@tikzpath@\pgfpictureid @#1\endcsname}}}}%
  },
  remembered path/.code={%
    \pgfutil@IfUndefined{qrr@tikzpath@\pgfpictureid @#1}{}{%
      \tikz@addmode{%
        \expandafter\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath
        \expandafter{\csname qrr@tikzpath@\pgfpictureid @#1\endcsname}}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[left color=blue, right color=green] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\clip[remembered path=box];
\draw (0,0) -- (2,1);
\path[remember path=box] (0.5, 0) rectangle (1.5, 1) [reverse clip];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

#### First compilation

[image]

#### Second compilation

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing a `save to aux` key with the `spath3` library but … it doesn't write anything to the `aux` file unless I use it after the path (and not on it). ☹

Comment: Very interesting! Why +-16000pt? Is it the largest possible dimension?

Comment: No, it's not. Technically, it's 16384pt (that's the maximum a length could be in TeX) but PGF itself uses only 16000 for a few internals – mainly bounding box stuff which might lead to weird things when using coordinates that lie outside this range. Of course, this doesn't apply here anyway because we want to ignore the bounding box to be updated in the first place. [By the way, 16000pt are well over 5 meters.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8260/16595) This should be plenty enough for most documents.