# Draw two concentric circles and a shaded area with associated text

Tags: tikz-pgf

For visualising the domain of definition of a function I want to create the following figure.
[image]

I use the following code.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};

\draw [thick] circle [radius=2];
\draw [thick] circle [radius=4];

\draw[double = gray!40, double distance=2cm, opacity=0.2] (0,0) circle (3);

\draw[->|, rotate around={30:(0,0)}] (0,0) -- (2,0)  node [midway,fill=white] {$2$};
\draw[->|, rotate around={60:(0,0)}] (0,0) -- (4,0)  node [midway,fill=white] {$4$};
\draw[fill=black](0,0) circle (2 pt) node [anchor=south east] {$O$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the following figure where I have added what I want to modify.
[image]

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Removing `fill=white` in the node option; adding `pos=.75` in the node option

Comment: Why don’t you create the diagram with the drawing program you used to make the red text and arrows?

Comment: @bubba It is just a basic screenshot program. I prefer tikz:-)!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could remove `fill=white` from the nodes and add `near end` (`pos=.75`) to the `4` node as such:

```
\draw[->|, rotate around={30:(0,0)}] (0,0) -- (2,0)  node [midway] {$2$};
\draw[->|, rotate around={60:(0,0)}] (0,0) -- (4,0)  node [near end] {$4$};
```

but this will give you
[image]
which doesn't look nice, does it?

Unfortunately, the [`mark connection node` decoration](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf/decoration/mark:connection:node) doesn't like [arrow tips](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99945/16595) but for straight paths, you just place the node first and then connect it with lines:

```
\path (0,0) -- node[near end] (4) {$4$} (60:4);
\draw[->|] (0,0) -- (4) -- (60:4);
```

---

Since this involves using each coordinate/name at least twice, I'll suggest putting this into a `to path`.

This needs some extra work because it uses an `edge` (which is also a `to`):

- `line to` to get the original `--(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes` to path (and not the one we are just defining),
- `path only` to force no drawing, no filling, …,
- all nodes along the path are aliased `@nodeonline@` so we can use them later (the `coordinate` is a fallback in case no node has been used with the `to` path) and
- sneaking in the `\tikztonodes` from the parent `to` but the internal version.

The latter uses `\unexpanded` in case there are any fragile macros part of the nodes (not your case).

---

A [previous version of this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/667341/1) provided a different solution that was more complicated than it needed to be (but didn't use any TikZ internals as this one does).

I prefer this one because it is as close to normal TikZ usage and can be used repeatedly on a path without the path being interrupted:

```
\tikz[inner sep=.15em, circle, nodes=draw, sloped]
  \draw[ultra thick, ->, node on line] (0,0) to["0"] (1,1)
                                             to["1"] (2,0)
                                             to["2"] (4,1);
```

[image]

---

If this is needed for more than one node, a bit more work is necessary.

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, quotes}% quotes for "syntax" on edges/tos
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  node on line/.style={
    to path={
      \pgfextra{%
        \edef\tikz@temp{% rescuing nodes and target for edge
          edge[
            line to, path only, % line to = --, path only = no draw, no fill, …
            every edge quotes/.append style={auto=false},% node *on* the line
            nodes={alias=@nodeonline@}]
          coordinate(@nodeonline@)% fallback coordinate
          \unexpanded\expandafter{\tikz@tonodes}(\tikztotarget)
        }\expandafter
      }\tikz@temp
      -- (@nodeonline@) -- (\tikztotarget)}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9, -4.9) grid (4.9, 4.9);
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-5, 0) -- (5, 0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] ( 0,-5) -- (0, 5) node[above]{$y$};

\draw [thick] circle [radius=2]
              circle [radius=4];

\draw[double = gray!40, double distance=2cm, opacity=0.2] (0,0) circle [radius=3];

% Short: polar coordinate and "syntax"
\draw[->|] (0,0) to[node on line, "$2$"] (30:2);
% Long:  rotate around and literal node after to
\draw[->|, rotate around={60:(0,0)}] % long form (short: "$4$" near end)
  (0,0) to[node on line] node[near end]{$4$} (4,0);

\draw[fill=black](0,0) circle [radius=2pt]
                       node [anchor=south east] {$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: +1! Where is defined `\NewDocumentCommand` option `r`? Your example works also if in definition of `\nodeOnArrow` command instead of `r` I use  `d`.

Comment: @Zarko Page 2 of the [manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/xparse/0). The `r` stands for required (which it is) while `d` is optional (delimited). Though, even `r`/`R` act like an optional argument, providing a default value when it is missing *but* raising an error at the same time. Since both coordinates are needed, I chose `r`. (Sure we could default the first to `0, 0` but that makes it ambiguous if it'll work at all.) I usually try to avoid defining document commands for things that only work inside a TikZ picture but its usage as a `to path` is limited – at least in its current form.

Comment: Thank you very much for info and explanation. In first I didn't remember where is `\NewDocumentCommand` defined. BTW, for see my answer.  In comparison with your astonishing solution is mine quite primitive, but works ;-)

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to find documentation on the base LaTeX stuff. Your answer is using the same concept as mine (place a node and use it as the connection for two line segments) but you need to repeat coordinates (even if they're named) what I want to avoid.

Comment: @Zarko You made me think about the answer a bit more. After a few minutes digging into how edges actually work and how TikZ juggles the `\tikztonodes`, I've come up with a better solution, in my opinion.

Comment: huh, new solution is very demanding! I will need some time to figured out how it works.

Answer (score 8):

A solution with similar concept as in a @Qrrbrbirlbel answer but without advanced new command and Ti*k*T style  definition:

- for vectors are used  polar coordinates
- vectors are drawn in two steps:

  - first is determined position of vector label
  - after then is drawn vector

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[> = {Straight Barb[scale=1.2]}
                        ]
% circles
\draw[draw, double = gray!20, double distance=2cm] (0,0) circle [radius=3];
% axes
\draw[help lines, color=gray, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
%
\draw[->,thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};
% vectors
    \path (0,0) coordinate (o) 
                to node (lbl) {$2$} ++ (30:2);
\draw[->] (o) -- (lbl) -- (30:2);
    \path (o) to node[pos=0.75] (lbl) {$4$} ++(60:4);
\draw[->] (o) -- (lbl) -- (60:4);

\fill   (0,0) circle [radius=2pt] node [above left] {$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
A small variation od , for exercise:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\NewDocumentCommand{\nodeOnArrow}{O{} % arrow option; but not used in MWE
                                  r() % as requires, anchor of arrows label node
                                  r() % as requires, anchor for end arrow
                                  O{} % node options (position on arrow, etc)
                                  m}  % content of node
{
                                     \path[style={#1}] (#2) edge[path only]
                       node[append after command={
                            (#2)            edge (\tikzlastnode)
                            (\tikzlastnode) edge[-{Straight Barb[scale=1.2]}] (#3)
                                                  }, style={#4}] {$#5$} (#3);
} % end of command

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[draw, double = gray!20, double distance=2cm] (0,0) circle [radius=3];

\draw[->,thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};

\nodeOnArrow    (0,0) (20:2) {2}
\nodeOnArrow    (0,0) (60:4) [pos=0.75] {4}    % or "near end"

\draw[fill=black](0,0) circle [radius=2pt] node [above left] {$O$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as at the first example.

Answer (score 6):

Remove `fill=white` from your nodes. But then the line will pass through the text, so use `above` or `above left` to place them off the line. You can set values, e.g., `above=-1pt` to move the labels closer or farther away from the line. Finally, `pos=` will set the position (as a percentage of the total length) of the node. For example, `midway` is the same as `pos=.5`.

Also, you should use `circle[radius=2pt]` instead of `circle (2 pt)`, which is deprecated (but still works for now).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};

\draw [thick] circle [radius=2];
\draw [thick] circle [radius=4];

\draw[double = gray!40, double distance=2cm, opacity=0.2] (0,0) circle (3);

\draw[->|, rotate around={30:(0,0)}] (0,0) -- (2,0)  node [above=-1pt, midway] {$2$};
\draw[->|, rotate around={60:(0,0)}] (0,0) -- (4,0)  node [above left=-3pt, pos=.75] {$4$};
\draw[fill=black](0,0) circle[radius=2pt] node [above left] {$O$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another method, admittedly not what exactly asked for, but still valid in my opinion, would be to use `sloped` to place the node tangent to the current slope of the path (in the case of a segment, the node will be parallel to the segment). Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};

\draw [thick] circle [radius=2];
\draw [thick] circle [radius=4];

\draw[double = gray!40, double distance=2cm, opacity=0.2] (0,0) circle (3);

\draw[->|] (0,0) -- (30:2)  node [midway, sloped, above] {$2$};
\draw[->|] (0,0) -- (60:4)  node [near end, sloped, above] {$4$};
\draw[fill=black](0,0) circle (2 pt) node [anchor=south east] {$O$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I had to remove the parameter `rotate around=` and use instead polar coordinates, otherwise `sloped` did not work (not sure what's going on here).

Just for fun, here is an "improved" version with squiggly lines, as per the original picture:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations,decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[squigglyline/.style={decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=1pt,amplitude=0.2pt}}]

\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed, squigglyline] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[->,ultra thick,squigglyline] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,ultra thick,squigglyline] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};

\draw [thick,squigglyline] circle [radius=2];
\draw [thick,squigglyline] circle [radius=4];

\draw[double = gray!40, double distance=2cm, opacity=0.2,squigglyline] (0,0) circle (3);

\draw[->|,squigglyline] (0,0) -- (30:2)  node [midway, sloped, above] {$2$};
\draw[->|,squigglyline] (0,0) -- (60:4)  node [near end, sloped, above] {$4$};
\draw[fill=black](0,0) circle (2 pt) node [anchor=south east] {$O$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting! The coordinates that TikZ gives to the PGF macro that does the rotation are the untransformed one, i.e. `(2, 0)` (or rather `\pgfqpoint {56.90549pt}{0.0pt}`) and the angle from `(0, 0)` to `(2, 0)` is obviously 0°. `\draw[rotate around={20:(0,0)}](0,0)--(30:4)node[sloped]{$4$};` is giving a half rotated `4`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion.

[image]

```
% https://www.overleaf.com/read/khkhbwgqmjvt
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % for Barb arrow
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Straight Barb[angle=60:5pt]}]
\fill[yellow!50,even odd rule,draw=black] circle(2) circle(4);
\draw[gray!50,dashed] (-4.5,-4.5) grid (4.5,4.5);
\draw 
(-5,0)--(5,0) node[below]{$x$}
(0,-5)--(0,5) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[->,red] (0,0)--(30:2) node[pos=.8,below]{$2$};
\draw[->,blue] (0,0)--(60:4) node[pos=.7,below right] {$4$};
\draw[fill=white] circle(1.5pt) node[below left]{$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{asy}
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
size(10cm);
unitsize(1cm);
import graph;
import math;  // for grid
real r=2,R=4;
pair O=(0,0);
path p=circle(O,r),q=circle(O,R);
add(shift(-4,-4)*grid(8,8,gray+.2pt+dashed));
filldraw(p^^q,evenodd+green+opacity(.2));
draw(Label("$2$",Relative(.7),align=S),O--r*dir(30),red,Arrow(TeXHead));
draw(Label("$4$",Relative(.8),align=SE),O--R*dir(60),blue,Arrow(TeXHead));
dot("$O$",align=SW,O,FillDraw(white,black));
xaxis("$x$",-R-.5,R+.5);
yaxis("$y$",-R-.5,R+.5);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```